# XJC xs:choice inheritance

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, jaxb2, xjc

I am having a problem getting xjc to generate a class with choice group extension that maintains order.  The following schema is an example.

```
<xs:complexType name="base">
  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="a" />
    <xs:element name="b" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="extended">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="base">
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="c" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The problem is that this results in both base and extended classes to contain a list property instead of extended just adding to the base list property so that order can be maintained in the case of the following xml:

```
<extended>
  <a />
  <c />
  <b />
</extended>
```

I tried manually setting the property names to the same in my binding.xjb, but it is complaining because of a naming collision.

Comment: While Jerome's answer corrects my xsd to be valid, I am still looking for an answer to making the choice of the child override the parent in XJC

Answer (score 2):

Here, you want to extend the list of possible choices, not the type. To do so, you should use a schema like this :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="base">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="baseGroup"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="extended">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="extendedGroup"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:group name="baseGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="a" />
      <xs:element name="b" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:group name="extendedGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:group ref="baseGroup" />
      <xs:element name="c" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

I've tried to validate the following file on http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ with the above xmlschema and it works without error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<extended>
  <a />
  <c />
  <b />
</extended>
```

Comment: Okay, I was also going this route, but I was under the incorrect impression that my xsd was valid, however I was unaware that there is an implicit sequence when extending that makes an <a> or <b> after <c> invalid. However the issue still remains that I do need to keep the extension and get xjc to write them to the same list property.